# Sharepoint Integration - Distributing Sharepoint DLLs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

Am a sharepoint newbie. Couldn't find a post that addresses my questions. If this is a duplicate please point me to an existing question.

I have to implement a simple document upload integration from existing asp.net mvc 2 site to a sharepoint site for one our clients.

At this point am not sure what version of Sharepoint client uses (2010/2007).

Couple of questions in this regard:

1) For 2010: I have tried to understand the licensing of Sharepoint Client Model Redistributable and could not understand if I can just provide Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/Runtime.dll along with my web application package or should I have to install the reditributable package on client's server?

2) For 2007: I think I can use WSS 3.0 to access Sharepoint Web Services (I could be totally wrong and haven't even tried this yet). If that's the case, can I just distribute the dll's along with my web application package (if that's feasible)?

**Update-1:**

Found this SO post for my first question: [SharePoint Client Object Model Assembly Distribution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32177/sharepoint-client-object-model-assembly-distribution)

**Update-2:**

@bsimser was kind enough to shed some light on the questions I had and the @jabbr chat is @ https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/sharepoint , will keep this question open any possible inputs from other experts.

Comment: Do not leave this hanging. If you have answers (even just one liners) post them here. These links posted here can/will go stale over time and others that come across this page will be forever left without an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just open the unc path to the document library and save the file. You would not need any Sharepoint Client object.

\sharepointsite\sites\sitename\libraryname